# Recruiter asked me to touch base after immigration but have not replied

Tags: interviewing, applications

A few month ago I had two phone interview at a large tech company. The second one was a follow up as they weren't sure about the first one. At the time, I was transitioning from OPT to H1B for my current job (selected for 2020 lottery but petition was not yet approved). My recruiter called me and told me that I passed the second phone interview, but he could not proceed with my application because of the status of my immigration. He said he was technically suppose to outright reject me but to do me a favor he wanted me to contact him again once my H1B petition was approved. He implied the position may or may not be gone but he might be able to help me find other suitable positions.

I did that on Monday after my petition was approved. Two days later, I have yet to received a reply. My application is still open and still indicates that I'm being considered after the phone interview, so I don't think he was just bluffing. I'm walking on ice here but should I contact him again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: I think that answer is too general for what I’m asking. There was essentially a “pause” in my interview process and it was a “pause” because the recruiter was being nice. He asked me to contact him later but now he’s not responding.

Comment: Have you checked on LinkedIn whether the recruiter still works for the company? Also with COVID-19, they may be stood down, not working, off sick, etc.

Comment: Since you mention H1B I will assume english is not your first language (although this mistake is also fairly common among native english speakers), for your future reference the correct phrase is "touch bases", not basis.

See: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/touch-base/

Comment: Have you called this individual?  I cannot count the number of emails that I wanted to reply to, but due to everything else going on, failed to actually reply to.   Easier for me to talk on the phone, harder to ignore, with that ringing and all that jazz.

Comment: @Donald I should have approached him with that but did not. It would be hard to schedule a call now given the fact that I already emailed him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, for slow rolling recruitment scenarios like this, it is considered pushy to follow up in less than a week.  (For some competitive high velocity recruitment situation, it can be different).  Some people do take a couple days of vacation now and again, remember.  Give it a week, follow up.  “Eagerly waiting to hear...”

You may want to check and make sure the recruiter is still there on LinkedIn, plenty of layoffs lately. If you go a couple rounds without getting a reply I would try to contact the recruiting department more generally, if they have a system showing your application as open.